# Argument not posted with Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

This Ajax request works but it seems like the argument is not posted to the getHint.php (`$_POST['targetId']` is empty). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks

```
postAjaxRequestFunktion(minFunktion, 'getHint.php', 'targetId = ' + playId)

         function postAjaxRequestFunktion(minFunk,minUrl, mittArg)
         {
            var contenttype = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            var minRequest        = new skapaAjaxObjekt(minFunk)
            if (!minRequest) return false
            minRequest.open('POST', minUrl, true)
            minRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type',   contenttype)
            minRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-length', mittArg.length)
            minRequest.setRequestHeader('Connection',     'close')
            minRequest.send(mittArg)
            return true
         }


         function skapaAjaxObjekt(minFunk)
         {
            try       { var   minRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()                   }
            catch(e1) { try { minRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")    }
            catch(e2) { try { minRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") }
            catch(e3) { minRequest = false }}}
            if (minRequest) minRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 &&
                   this.responseText != null)
                     minFunk.call(this.responseText)
            }

            return minRequest
         }  

         function minFunktion()
         {
             hintArray = eval('(' + this + ')');    
         }
```

getHint.php:

```
$targetId = $_POST['targetId'];
```

Comment: Could you please show us your HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure what HTML it is that you need to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i advice you to use a js lib jQuery where ajax requests are more simple..
also at php file use
var_dump($_POST); 
will give you more info

Comment: Thank you, jQuery was a lot easier.